# How to use emoji in android?

Tags: android

I am working on a chat app using firebase, and now I want to use emoji in my app.
Can any one tell me how yo use emoji in android.

So I want to have a keyboard in my app that has emoji just like Whatsapp or Hangouts. How can I do that? I want to leave my key keyboard as it is I just want to add tabs to put emojis. I would think it would be easily supported by the soft keyboard but I can find nothing so far. Anyone could tell how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Emoji are just characters. TextViews output them as expected, soft keyboards provide them on input.

Just make sure your wire/file/database formats handle Unicode, and specifically multiword UTF-16 codepoints, correctly. E. g. don't assume one byte per character, and when working with Java UTF-16 strings, don't assume one char per codepoint.